# How to fix the memory leak in the TetheringManager

Tags: android

I find there is memory leak in the Settings App(Hotspot & tethering)(Android R), which call the TetheringManager.

1. TetheringManager call the "registerTetheringEventCallback" in the constructor, but don't call
   "unregisterTetheringEventCallback".
2. I use the profile tool to find leak mTetheringEventCallback reference by TetheringManager, so TetherSettings can not be GC.

I can't find the solution to fix them. Please help to fix them. Thanks.

```
   @SystemApi(client = MODULE_LIBRARIES)
    public TetheringManager(@NonNull final Context context,
            @NonNull Supplier<IBinder> connectorSupplier) {
        mContext = context;
        mCallback = new TetheringCallbackInternal(this);
        mConnectorSupplier = connectorSupplier;

        final String pkgName = mContext.getOpPackageName();

        final IBinder connector = mConnectorSupplier.get();
        // If the connector is available on start, do not start a polling thread. This introduces
        // differences in the thread that sends the oneway binder calls to the service between the
        // first few seconds after boot and later, but it avoids always having differences between
        // the first usage of TetheringManager from a process and subsequent usages (so the
        // difference is only on boot). On boot binder calls may be queued until the service comes
        // up and be sent from a worker thread; later, they are always sent from the caller thread.
        // Considering that it's just oneway binder calls, and ordering is preserved, this seems
        // better than inconsistent behavior persisting after boot.
        if (connector != null) {
            mConnector = ITetheringConnector.Stub.asInterface(connector);
        } else {
            startPollingForConnector();
        }
        
        getConnector(c -> c.registerTetheringEventCallback(mCallback, pkgName));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a new function to call unregisterTetheringEventCallback. App can call the new function in OnDestory. I think this solution is the best.